# search for a substring in file name with built in windows search on Windows 11

Tags: windows-10, search, windows-11, windows-search, filenames

am using windows 11 and I find that the built in search facility is not working as expected.

I have a folder like this
[image]

and when I search it like this, I get no result.
[image]

I would like the search tool to have matched on the partial file name. but ideally I would like to have this working out of the box. Is there a setting to change or any other means to get partial file search match without installing additional software?
i checked solution, it was working for me on windows 7/8 but when upgraded to windows 11 it stopped working!